# Tags on blog that link to 404 page

Tags: bug, broken-link, blog

On the [Stack Overflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) there are links to tags on the side of the home page, but the tags that are titled 'serverfault.com' and 'superuser.com' link to a [404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) page.

> [image: Tags whose links are 404s]

[Helpful comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson):

> Huh, the dots get converted to dashes in the hyperlink, but the system
> still expects the dots to be in the URL to display the page, not
> dashes. [– animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson)

Comment: Two "Search" buttons ? Maybe that should be fixed too.

Comment: @JonasCz - Mea culpa. That's the tooltip for the search box. Apparently when I launched the snipping tool, Firefox decided to leave the tooltip up. I fixed the screenshot so it's not showing 2 apparent buttons

Comment: Huh, the dots get converted to dashes in the hyperlink, but the system still expects the dots to be in the URL to display the page, not dashes.

Comment: Reported on Meta SE before: [SE new blog: Broken link on 'serverfault.com' and 'superuser.com' under 'TAGS'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264171/260841)